# How reload jQuery var from another script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

I've stuck in this:

I've a jQuery script (cloudzoom), which using for zooming some images, pretty simple. It reads "a href="someimage.png" " as big image and "src img" as thumbnail. And I have another script, It change "a href" and "src img" on big image when I click on thumbnails. The problem is that cloudzoom don't read new "a href" and "img src" and show me old image zooming.

Is there a way to somehow call a "reloading" of cloudzoom var when I click on thumbnails?

Here is the script if somebody wants to see http://pastebin.com/UcNKUXrg

Comment: As you can see at the top of the script, when it is loaded and the DOM is ready, `$('.cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery').CloudZoom();` is run.  Try running that again after changing the `href` and `src` properties.

Comment: No luck at all. I'm completely disappointed.